# Django: Is it possible to add constraint on model level only (Not on DB level)

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to add a unique constraint on model level only (not on DB level) in Django?
So, the user cannot create the object from the Model without bypassing the validation, but can create them on DB level without the model validation.

Comment: Can you describe what functionality you want to be implemented and why a DB constraint doesn't/can't provide that? I don't understand the question.

Comment: In Ruby on Rails, we can put constraints such as unique, not null etc on Model level only, without having them on the database. So, the user cannot create the object from the Model without bypassing the validation, but can create them on DB level without the model validation.. That's all what I want.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - No...

But you can do it programmatically with obeying some rules. First of all, you shouldn't declare constraints as usual in model's fields definitions and `Meta`.

Second you should override save method of models, which you want containt (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods).

Third, it leads from the link's note - `Overridden model methods are not called on bulk operations` - so you should avoid modifing methods invoked from `.objects`, e.g. `.object.update()`. I'm not sure about `.objects.create` - would be great to test it or find docs link.